# Eclipse e4 product Export fail on Linux/Unix (plugin based product)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse e4 rcp application. When I want to export it on Linux it fail with this error message:

```
/home/marius/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86_64.xml:90: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/marius/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86_64.xml:664: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.500.v20190620-0530/scripts/genericTargets.xml:240: A problem occured while invoking the director.
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/marius/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/temp/org.eclipse.pde.container.feature/package.org.eclipse.pde.container.feature.linux.gtk.x86_64.xml:664: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.pde.build_3.10.500.v20190620-0530/scripts/genericTargets.xml:240: A problem occured while invoking the director.
```

The only thing I could find is this [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=546019) where he says in the last answer that he added this to his product file:

```
<feature id="org.eclipse.rcp" installMode="root"/>
<feature id="org.eclipse.pde" installMode="root"/>
```

But this can only work for feature based product and I have a **plug-in** based one.

How can I do something similar within a plug-in based product?

P.S.: A college on mine has the same problem on MacOs. On Windows everything works fine.

Comment: The Export RCP Wizard is deprecated and is accumulating problems as time goes by. The only really supported export is using Maven + Eclipse Tycho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the destination folder wasn't empty. Exporting into an empty folder works.